# Understanding Byte swapping

Tags: c, byte, endianness

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a little endian/big endian conversion for 64 bit integers (uint64_t) and while I find a lot of answers online as to how to do it, none of them explain what exactly is going on. For example, to get the nth byte of the integer I found this response:

`int x = (number >> (8*n)) & 0xff;`

Even though I understand the bit shifting component (shifting 8n digits to the right) I don't see where the & and 0xff come in, and what they mean aside from & is a bitwise AND operator.

So, how would this sort of logic apply to a big-endian/little-endian byte swapping method for 64 bit integers?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Endianness does not involve bit swapping, but only _byte_ swapping. From big to little endianess, you have to reverse the whole bytes making up the data word, leave the bits alone

Comment: `& 0xff` and similar masks off the 8 bits that need to be shifted (or were shifted) to the opposite endian byte. Usually the result will be `OR`red with the target value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might be easiest to think of an analogy with decimal numbers:

Take the number 308.  It has three digits, '3', '0', and '8'. By convention, digits to the left are more significant than digits to the right.  But the convention could just as easily have been the other way...the digits could've been written in reverse order (e.g., 803).

Why is this relevant?  Consider a hexadecimal representation of a number on a computer: 0xabcd0123.  In a mathematically rigorous sense, one can view this number as 4 radix-256 digits. (i.e., 0xab, 0xcd, 0x01, 0x23).  So, endianness is about the convention by which these radix-256 digits are ordered when written into memory.

Little-endian means "write the least significant digit to the lowest address";
Big-endian means "write the most significant digit to the lowest address".

So, on to the mechanics of processing endianness:
If you think of the decimal example above, how would you get each digit?  The least significant digit is given by taking the number modulo 10 (i.e., 308 % 10 = 8).  The second digit can be found by dividing the number by 10, then taking it modulo 10 (i.e., 308 / 10 = 30; 30 % 10  = 0) and so forth.

The process is exactly the same for binary data on a computer, except that it's treated as radix-256 instead of radix-10 like decimal digits.  This is where a few tricks come in.

1. When doing modulo with a modulus that is a power of 2, you can do it via AND.  Let m=256 as our modulus.  Because m = 2 to some power, x % m is equivalent to x & (m-1).  This is a numerical fact that is out-of scope for this answer.
2. When doing division by a power of 2, you can do it via right-shift.  That is, let m=256 be our divisor.  Because m = 2 to the 8th power, x / m is equivalent to x >> 8.

Thus binary endian-specific serialization uses exactly the process above:

`uint32_t val = 0xabcd0123;`

`(val & 0xff)` is equivalent to `(val % 256)`, and yields 0x23.

`((val >> 8) & 0xff)` is equivalent to `((val / 256) % 256)`, and yields 0x01.

`((val >> 16) & 0xff)` is equivalent to `(((val / 256)/256) % 256)`, and yields 0xcd.

and so on.  So now that you have access to the digits/bytes, you simply have to chose the order in which to store them.  Per above, "big endian = most-significant at lowest address", "little endian = least-significant at lowest address".

Comment: Nice first post.  Welcome!